# Override LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean without xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, ejb-3.0

First the question, then the explanation: I want to get rid of the Beans XML configuration and add some info to my EJB contexts.

I've here in my project (web part of the project) a class named `StatelessEjbSupportLocal` which extends `LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean` and this is the implementation:

```
public class StatelessEjbSupportLocal 
        extends LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean {

    private UserInfo userInfo;

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
             "org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory");
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099/");
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, 
                userInfo.getLogin() + ";" + userInfo.getHost());
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, userInfo.getIdUser());
        super.setJndiEnvironment(properties);
        refreshHome();
    }
    public UserInfo getUserInfo() {
        return userInfo;
    }

    public void setUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo) {
        this.userInfo = userInfo;
    }
}
```

And I have on my `apps.xml` with the beans configuration:

```
(...)
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.controller" />

<bean id="someBusiness" class="my.package.StatelessEjbSupportLocal">
    <property name="jndiName" value="SomeBusinessImpl/local" />
    <property name="businessInterface" value="my.package.business.SomeBusiness" />
    <property name="userInfo" ref="userInfo" />
</bean>
(...)
```

My web.xml has the configuration to load the above xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:apps.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

My `UserInfo` class is annotated with `@Component` and is filled on my `SecurityFilter` (configured on my web.xml as a filter) after the users login. I set the host, login and the id there and put it on the session.

It is all working fine. I have this because I set the user on the EJB SessionContext to get this info on an Interceptor on my Business (services) classes. That way I don't need to handed pass the user info to all my business implementations (I need this because on my connection I set the user info to the database with a procedure like some kind of pre-connection configuration to audit purposes).

What I would like to do is to get rid of the `beans` XML configuration on my `apps.xml`. In other words some kind of interceptor to this LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean that would set the UserInfo without the need of `<property name="userInfo" ref="userInfo" />` on every bean configuration.
Since I can have my `apps.xml` with just this:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.controller" />
```

And my `SomeBusiness` attribute on my managed bean annotated with `@Autowired` will work just fine.

Let me know if you need more information and I will edit this question with it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't pretty and I don't recommend it. You should either use a `@Bean` annotated method to construct the bean or keep your XML.

If you want still want to go ahead with this, annotate your `StatelessEjbSupportLocal` class with `@Component`. Annotate its `setUserInfo` with `@Autowired` and override the `setBusinessInterface` and `setJndiName` methods, annotating them with `@Value` with the value you want to use, and calling their super implementation. For example,

```
@Override
@Value("SomeBusinessImpl/local") // or reference some property
public void setJndiName(String jndiName) {
    super.setJndiName(jndiName);
}
```

Then declare the package containing `StatelessEjbSupportLocal` in your component scan.

**Edit By OP:**

As Sotirios Delimanolis recommended. I left the XML configuration.

Comment: I will follow your advice with the XML configuration. But for your suggestion, I don't quite follow this: `public void setJndiName(String jndiName)` where it should be overrided? Because with the `@Value("SomeBusinessImpl/local")` it only fit to this specific Business what about the hundred others on my application. Am I right on this question?

Comment: @JorgeCampos It should be overriden in your `StatelessEjbSupportLocal` class. [If you want to externalize the value used, you can do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592897/spring-retrieve-value-from-properties-file). (See the 2nd answer)

Comment: I would have to have a properties file instead of an XML =\ I will do it with XML configuration. Tomorrow when I get to work and put it to work i will accept your suggestion. Thanks for your time it is must appreciated.